# Entity Framework Migraciones en Biblioteca de Clases

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework-6

No hace mucho escribí un post exponiendo mis dificultades para realizar un proyecto diseñado con orientación al dominio. Este proyecto es una solución que se divide en varios proyectos:

- FrontEnd MVC
- ApiWebService (Web Api)
- Dominio (Biblioteca de clases Estándar)
- AccesoDatos (Biblioteca de Clases)(.NetCore / .Net)

Para esta pregunta nos centramos en la capa de Datos en la que tengo dos modelos **Restaurante** y **ValoracionesRestaurante**, me creo un DbContext llmado **ModelContext**.

Tampoco nos vamos a centrar en los modelos ya que son los que uso en todos los proyecto y están decorados con atributos `CodeFirst` que funcionan. **La cuestión es hacer una migración que me cree la base de datos por fin.**

*Establezco la capa de datos como proyecto de inicio*

> He probado en un proyecto con `.NET CORE` usando los mismos paquetes
>   pero los de Core.

la clase `DbContext` es la siguiente:

```
public class ModelContext : DbContext
{
    public ModelContext()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    //public ModelContext(DbContextOptions<ModelContext> options) 
    //    : base(options)
    //{

    //}
    public virtual DbSet<Restaurante> Restaurantes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ValoracionesRestaurante> ValoracionesRestaurantes { 
    get; set; }

    public static ModelContext Create()
    {
        return new ModelContext();
    }
}
```

La configuración está así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
    <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit 
        http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" 
        type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, 
        EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
        PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
   </configSections>
   <connectionStrings configSource="connections.config"/>
   <entityFramework>
       <defaultConnectionFactory 
       type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, 
       EntityFramework">
           <parameters>
               <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
           </parameters>
       </defaultConnectionFactory>
       <providers>
           <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
               type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, 
                EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
            </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    ...
</configuration>
```

La cadena de conexión apunta a un fichero llamado **connections.config** con la cadena original:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ModelContext" 
            connectionString="data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;
            initial catalog=AccesoDatos.ModelContext;
            integrated security=True;
            MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
            App=EntityFramework" 
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Excepción que me lanza al hacer `Add-Migration InitialCreate`:

> `No DbContext was found in assembly 'AccesoDatos'. Ensure that you're
>   using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor
>   generic.`

Answer (score 0):

Cosas a tener en cuenta con Migrations de Entity Framework 6:

1. Tener instalada la **consola de comandos** de Entity Framework mediante el paquete NuGet: `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`
2. Si la **cadena de conexión** la tenemos en un fichero de configuración se tomará el nombre y se le pasará como parámetro al constructor base de DbContext.

Ejemplo fichero de configuración

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="BloggingContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PoCBbddCodeFirst;Integrated Security=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Ejemplo clase DbContext

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public BloggingContext() : base("name=BloggingContext") { }

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
}
```

3. Al abrir la consola de administración de paquetes debemos **asegurarnos de haber seleccionado el proyecto de la capa de datos** como proyecto predeterminado, ya que en este irá a buscar las clases que hereden de DbContext[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
4. Para iniciar la configuración del proyecto en las migraciones de Entity Framework primero hay que **habilitarlo**. Si queremos evitar problemas se recomienda hacer el proyecto de datos como "Proyecto de Inicio" en ese momento, obviamente no es para depurarlo en ese momento, sino que la herramienta de migraciones irá a buscar las cadenas de conexión al mismo y si aún no las tenemos insertadas no podrá encontrarlas. Para habilitar las migraciones en el proyecto se realiza el comando `Enable-Migrations`, que creará la carpeta "Migrations" y el fichero "Configuration.cs"
5. Luego se crea el "**scaffolding**" de la base de datos mediante el comando: `Add-Migration InitialCreate`. Teniendo en cuenta que `InitialCreate` es un nombre que podemos definir nosotros a nuestro antojo.
6. Y por último para pasar la **migración** a la base de datos se utiliza el comando `Update-Database`

@DaniGala el mensaje que te da suele ocurrir cuando no has seleccionado bien el proyecto predeterminado para la consola de administración de paquetes. Por otro lado en el código que nos muestras lo único que no me cuadra es el nombre de la conexión (`ModelContext`) que es distinto al que le pasas en el constructor (`DefaultConnection`) y creo que también te puede terminar dando problemas.

Si lo terminas resolviendo sácanos de dudas y coméntalo.

Answer (score 0):

Implementando un proyecto ASP.Net Web app, páginas Razor, tipo Onion básico, con tres capas, dos proyectos tipo Biblioteca de clases más la UI, ensayé las opciones posibles:

1. Poniendo los Nugets en una capa, varias capas, todas las capas.
2. Varié marcando el proyecto predeterminado para los tres casos.
3. Desde la consola de administrador cuidé de estar en la ruta correcta del modelo y el DbContext.
4. Violando la arquitectura limpia, pase el modelo para la capa API.
5. Igual pasé el DbContext y dejé el Modelo en la capa de infraestructura (proyecto tipo biblioteca de clases)
6. Nugets de EF en distintas versiones...
7. Etc, etc, etc.

Y ni para qué ensayar creando la migración y luego pasando todo a la capa correspondiente.

Solo funciona o migra (Code First), SIN Bibliotecas de Clases.

No sucede esto cuando se hace uso de un proyecto distinto, MCV, Consola, Blazor, etc.

Nota: Cadena de conexión, registro del servicio en el contenedor de inyección (program), etc... todo Ok!. VS 2022, Net Core 6.0 y 7.0., etc.

La combinación fue a lo grande.

Sigo investigando y les comentaré....

César